# Rails join three models and compute the sum of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need some help over here to understand how the model relationship works on rails. Let me explain the scenario.

I have created 3 models.

1. Properties
2. Units
3. Rents

Here is the how relationship mapped for them.

Model #property.rb

```
 class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :units
      has_many :rents, :through=> :unit
    end
```

Model #unit.rb

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :rents
end
```

Model #rent.rb

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

here is the the schema

```
     create_table "units", :force => true do |t|
        t.integer  "property_id"
        t.string   "number"
        t.decimal  "monthly_rent"
      end

 create_table "rents", :force => true do |t|
        t.integer  "unit_id"
        t.string   "month"
        t.string   "year"
        t.integer  "user_id"
      end
```

OK, here is my problem. Let's say I have 2 properties

- property A
- property B

and

- property A has unit A01,A02,A03
- property B has unit B01,B02,B03

I need to generate a report which shows the SUM of all the outstanding rents based on the property and month

So here is how it should be looks like. (tabular format)

- Property A - December - RENT SUM GOES HERE
- Property B - December - RENT SUM GOES HERE

So I got all the properties first. But I really can't figure out a way to merge the properties and units (I guess we don't need the rents model for this part) and print them in the view. Can someone help me to do this. Thanks

```
  def outstanding_by_properties

    @properties = Property.find(:all)
    @units = Unit.find(:all,:select=>"SUM(monthly_rent) as total,property_id",:conditions=>['property_id IN (?)',@properties])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work for you. Hopefully an SQL guru will come along and check my work. I'm assuming your Property model has a "name" field for "Property A," etc.--you should change it to whatever your field is called.

```
def outstanding_by_properties
  Property.all  :select => "properties.name, rents.month, SUM(units.monthly_rent) AS rent_sum",
                :joins => { :units => :rents },
                :group => "properties.id, rents.month, rents.year"
end
```

This should return an array of Property objects that have the attributes `name`, `month`, and `rent_sum`.

It basically maps to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT properties.name, rents.month, SUM(units.monthly_rent) AS rent_sum
FROM properties
  JOIN units ON properties.id = units.property_id
  JOIN rents ON units.id = rents.unit_id
GROUP BY properties.id, rents.month, rents.year
```

The JOINs connect rows from all three tables and the GROUP BY makes it possible to do a SUM for each unique combination of property and month (we have to include year so that e.g. December 2008 is not grouped together with December 2009).

Comment: Hi Jordan, Thank you so much for the post.I tried your example with some modifications as I need to show the total rents sum and total rents received. that is SUM(units.monthly_rent) and SUM(rents.total_amount). but I always get ONLY the SUM of rents table.

Comment: @properties =  Property.all  :select => "properties.name, rents.month, SUM(units.monthly_rent) AS rent_sum,SUM(rents.total_amount) AS rent_received",
                :joins => { :units => :rents },
                :group => "properties.id, rents.month, rents.year",:conditions=> {:properties=>{:landlord_id => current_user.id},:rents=>{:year => 2009,:month=>12}}

Comment: You didn't mention a "total_amount" column on the rents table. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm sorry yeah, I just excluded some parts from the original code, just to keep things simple for you guys. I use the rents table to keep the paid rents. I understand that I can get it from the units table too. But in the current setup when a user pays the rents I insert the unit_id,total_amount,month,year. The value on rents.total_amount is always same as units.monthly_rent.